# Smoothing walk animations in unity (2D Unity in C#)

Tags: c#, animation, unity-game-engine, lerp

So what we're trying to do is have smooth movement for our player character as they walk. The walk is dictated by user input via arrow keys. She's got an animation class and a collider class attached to her to keep her walk cycle going and keep her on the game board. The problem is it will only move one jerking motion at a time as opposed to continuing to move when the arrow key is help down. Any suggestions?

```
using UnityEngine;
using System.Collections;

public class GridMove : MonoBehaviour
{

    private float moveSpeed = 128f;
    private float gridSize = 64f;
    private enum Orientation { Horizontal, Vertical };

    private Orientation gridOrientation = Orientation.Horizontal;
    private bool allowDiagonals = false;
    private bool correctDiagonalSpeed = true;
    private Vector2 input;
    public bool isMoving = false;
    private Vector3 startPosition, endPosition;
    private float t;
    private float factor;

    public bool wallLeft = false;
    public bool wallRight = false;
    public bool wallUp = false;
    public bool wallDown = false;

    void Start()
    {
        startPosition = transform.position;

    }
    // Update is called once per frame
    void Update()
    {
        CheckInput();


        if (isMoving)
        {
            transform.position = endPosition;
            isMoving = false;
        }

        if (!isMoving)
        {
            input = new Vector2(Input.GetAxis("Horizontal"), Input.GetAxis("Vertical"));
            if (!allowDiagonals)
            {
                if (Mathf.Abs(input.x) > Mathf.Abs(input.y))
                {
                    input.y = 0;
                }
                else
                {
                    input.x = 0;
                }
            }

            if (input != Vector2.zero)
            {
                StartCoroutine(move(transform));
            }
        }

    }

    public IEnumerator move(Transform transform)
    {
        isMoving = true;
        startPosition = transform.position;
        t = 0;

        if (allowDiagonals && correctDiagonalSpeed && input.x != 0 && input.y != 0)
        {
            factor = 0.7071f;
        }
        else
        {
            factor = 1f;
        }

        while (t < 1f)
        {
            t += Time.deltaTime * (moveSpeed / gridSize) * factor;
            transform.position = Vector3.Lerp(startPosition, endPosition, t);
            yield return null;
        }

        isMoving = false;
        yield return 0;
    }
    private void CheckInput()
    {
        if (Input.GetKeyDown(KeyCode.D) || Input.GetKeyDown(KeyCode.RightArrow) && wallRight == false)
        {
            endPosition += Vector3.right * gridSize;
            isMoving = true;
        }
        else if (Input.GetKeyDown(KeyCode.A) || Input.GetKeyDown(KeyCode.LeftArrow) && wallLeft == false)
        {
            endPosition -= Vector3.right * gridSize;
            isMoving = true;
        }
        else if (Input.GetKeyDown(KeyCode.W) || Input.GetKeyDown(KeyCode.UpArrow) && wallUp == false)
        {
            endPosition += Vector3.up * gridSize;
            isMoving = true;
        }
        else if (Input.GetKeyDown(KeyCode.S) || Input.GetKeyDown(KeyCode.DownArrow) && wallDown == false)
        {
            endPosition -= Vector3.up * gridSize;
            isMoving = true;
        }
    }

}
```

COLLIDER SCRIPT

```
using UnityEngine;
using System.Collections;

public class Collider : MonoBehaviour 
{
    void OnTriggerEnter2D(Collider2D col)
    {
        Debug.Log("enter");

        if (col.CompareTag("left wall"))
        {
            Debug.Log("i see a little sillouetto of a man");
            GetComponent<GridMove>().wallLeft = true;
            Debug.Log("left");
        }
        else if (col.CompareTag("right wall"))
        {
            GetComponent<GridMove>().wallRight = true;
        }
        else if (col.CompareTag("up wall"))
        {
            GetComponent<GridMove>().wallUp = true;
        }
        else if (col.CompareTag("down wall"))
        {
            GetComponent<GridMove>().wallDown = true;
        }
    }

    void OnTriggerExit2D(Collider2D col)
    {
        if (col.CompareTag("left wall"))
        {
            GetComponent<GridMove>().wallLeft = false;
        }
        else if (col.CompareTag("right wall"))
        {
            GetComponent<GridMove>().wallRight = false;
        }
        else if (col.CompareTag("up wall"))
        {
            GetComponent<GridMove>().wallUp = false;
        }
        else if (col.CompareTag("down wall"))
        {
            GetComponent<GridMove>().wallDown = false;
        }
    }

}
```

Comment: Is It the animation not being smooth or It's just the movement/speed smoothness?

Comment: i dont really get why you use that coroutine in update instead of just moving how far you can per frame as long as the button is held down. im quite sure the issue also lies burried there, but as long as i dont understand why it needs to be there, i cant give any further advise.

Answer (score 0):

Your code has a few more issues that could be cleaned up. But to fix your problem with the code you have just change your update loop to the following.

```
void Update()
{
    if(!isMoving) 
    {
        CheckInput();

        if(isMoving) 
        {
            input = new Vector2(Input.GetAxis("Horizontal"), Input.GetAxis("Vertical"));
            if(!allowDiagonals) 
            {
                if(Mathf.Abs(input.x) > Mathf.Abs(input.y)) 
                {
                    input.y = 0;
                } else 
                {
                    input.x = 0;
                }
            }

            StartCoroutine(move(transform));
        }
    }
}
```